# how to reduce size of node_module in angular app and load Node_Modules from index.html or application root

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I want to reduce size of node_module (current size 605MB) and load Node_Modules from index.html or application root.

Angular 5
node 8.9.4

I tried few solutions but not giving expected result,
`npm install --production`

- https://github.com/salsita/grunt-package-minifier: Minimizes
  space taken by node modules and their dependencies. -- gulp --- npm
  as a build tool(https://www.npmjs.com/package/build-tools)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/modclean: Remove unwanted files
  and directories from your node_modules folder
- https://ivanjov.com/what-is-npm-shrinkwrap-and-why-you-should-start-using-it-right-now/, https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap.html: Lock down
  dependency versions for publication
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1161529/%2FArticles%2F1161529%2FA-Note-on-Angular-Deployment-and-Node-Modules:
  Manually Copy the Files and Change the References
- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe -- reduce duplication

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but Node Modules are not supposed to be part of/bundled with your application, but imported into the application with "import" statement. Angular uses webpack to "tree shake" your imported modules, to avoid dublicates and minimize size.

Example: To use moment 3rd party library:

```
npm install moment --save
```

then place this line in top of your component/service

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

And then you can use moment in this file

```
let myDate = moment();
```

Many libraries are even built so you can import only a part of the library to reduce size even more.

Comment: Yes am aware about "Node Modules are not supposed to be part of/bundled with your application", but as i mentioned in question am looking for a way to reduce size of node_module so am trying different way.